# How to use countif to find specific formulas

Tags: google-spreadsheets

I'm using Google Sheet. I have a bunch of `=char(10003)` to show check marks in some cells.

I want to use `=countif` to count them all.

I'm stuck at what to write for the `criterion` parameter.

How can I find specific formulas using `countif`?

Answer (score 1):

## Cell value is `✓`

Counts the number of cells whose value is the check **`✓`** character ***while also*** containing a formula.

```
=SUM(MAP(range, LAMBDA(v,
   ISFORMULA(v)*(v="✓"))))
```

- Replace **`range`** in the formula above with a valid range reference such as **`A2:D14`**
- It doesn't matter whether you use the **`✓`** or its equivalent code **`CHAR(10003)`** in the formula.
- The formula will not differentiate between **`="✓"`** and **`=CHAR(10003)`** as both display the **`✓`** character and both are also formulas.

## Cell value includes `✓`

Counts the number of cells whose value includes the check **`✓`** character ***while also*** containing a formula.

```
=SUM(MAP(range, LAMBDA(v, 
   ISFORMULA(v)*(IFERROR(FIND("✓",v))))))
```

- Same as the previous formula but uses FIND to search each value for the **`✓`** character and IFERROR to remove any errors triggered where not found.

---

#### Google Docs Editors Help, Function Links

[FIND](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094126?hl=en)  [IFERROR](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304?hl=en)  [ISFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6270316?hl=en)  [LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718?hl=en)  [MAP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568985?hl=en)  [SUM](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093669?hl=en)